# Jquery google like image grid

Tags: jquery, image, grid

Does anyone know of an image gallery using jquery that scales images and places them like in an image google search (eg. all images on straight rows even though a row can contain different amount of images depending on width of the image)

(not like a montage as masorny)

Thanks

Comment: before asking question please try to show your effort, so that other can help you !!.

Comment: [What have you found / tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have tried gpop, masorny, atteeeeention, isotope, jglance.

Comment: i want something similare to this: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/, but to have the images fill the row and maybe increase the space between the images. To achive a nice gird. I can control the height of each image

Answer (score 1):

Check out this jQuery Plugin: https://github.com/brunjo/rowGrid.js.
It places items like in the Google image search.